# Room - queries in generic base class (especially flow queries)

Tags: android, android-room

In room, it seems to be impossible to use annotation based setups in a generic class with variable based data or with provided classes - the result is that there is no workaround to define queries with `Flow` inside an abstract generic base class.

Is that really try?

**Examples 1 - CAN BE SOLVED**

Define a query which contains a table name that is defined by a class variable

```
@Dao
abstract class BaseDao<Item : IItem, ItemWithRef> {

    abstract val tableName: String
    
    // DOES NOT WORK - because table name is not compile-time constant
    @Transaction
    @Query("select * from ${tableName}")
    abstract suspend fun loadAll(): List<ItemWithRef>
    
    // SOLUTION
    private val rawQueryLoadAll
        get() = "SELECT * FROM $tableName"
    @Transaction
    @RawQuery
    protected abstract suspend fun loadAll(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): List<ItemWithRef>
    suspend fun loadAll(): List<ItemWithRef> = loadAll(queryLoadAll)
    
}
```

**Examples 2 - CAN NOT BE SOLVED?**

Define flow queries which contains a table name that is defined by a class variable

Here the problem is, that `@RawQuery` needs to know the queries classes - can this somehow be solved as well?

```
@Dao
abstract class BaseDao<Item : IItem, ItemWithRef> {

    abstract val tableName: String
    
    // all 3 possibilities DO NOT WORK 
    // - because `@RawQuery` needs to know that it handles `ItemWithRef::class`
    // - because the table name is not constant
    
    
    // DOES NOT WORK 
    @Transaction
    @Query("select * from ${tableName}")
    abstract suspend fun flowAll(): Flow<List<ItemWithRef>>
    
    // DOES NOT WORK 
    @Transaction
    @RawQuery
    protected abstract fun flowAll(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): Flow<List<ItemWithRef>>
    fun flowAll(): Flow<List<ItemWithRef>> = flowAll(queryLoadAll)
    
    // DOES NOT WORK
    @Transaction
    @RawQuery(observedEntities = arrayOf(ItemWithRef::class))
    protected abstract fun flowAll(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): Flow<List<ItemWithRef>>
    fun flowAll(): Flow<List<ItemWithRef>> = flowAll(queryLoadAll)
    
}
```

**Question**

I'm fine with the workaround for example 1 but is there any workaround to also define a `Flow` raw query in a base class somehow?

Comment: Query annotation does not take String expr parameters like `"the $name"` , instead it uses `"the :name"` type params.

Comment: I know, but this does only allow to use function parameters... this can be circumvented by providing `tableName` as default value, but this does not change anything on my example (function wise or problem wise)

Comment: I don't think it'll be easy , see [this](https://github.com/android/sunflower/tree/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/data) , they created 2 DAO's